# AsyncTask not accessible in Service

Tags: android

My app does the following:

Activity1 starts Activity2.
Acitivity2 starts a Service.
The Service uses a AsyncTask to download a file.

In the AsyncTask I have a piece of code like this:

```
while ((status == 0)) {

            byte buffer[];
            if (size - downloaded > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            } else {
                buffer = new byte[size - downloaded];
            }

            int read = stream.read(buffer);
            if (read == -1)
                break;

            file.write(buffer, 0, read);
            downloaded += read;

  }
```

Everything works like expected. With the `status` variable I can start and stop my download depending on its value.

BUT, when I close Activity2 and start it again (the service keeps running), I cannot stop the download, which means the variable `status` is not read correctly. I checked the variable, the value is OK but the Asynctask does not recognize it.

How can I get back control over my AsyncTask?

I made some more tests but this time with a thread, to make sure its not a failure in how I handle the AsyncTask. I did it this way:

Activity2 starts the Service (I did not change any code here). 
The Service creates an `Download` Object what downloads the file using a Thread.

The structure looks like this:

```
in the Service
private Download dl = new Download();

private final DMInterface.Stub mBinder = new DMInterface.Stub() {

    public void downloadFile() throws DeadObjectException {
        try {
            dl.start(url) // This starts a thread and the download

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws DeadObjectException {
        dl.cancel(); //This stops the download
    }

};
```

And again, everything works until I disconnect from the service. Why am I only able to control the thread when I don't disconnect from the service?

Here is the code where I start/bind the service to Activity2 (only they important parts):

```
public class Activity2 extends ListActivity {

  private DMInterface dmInterface;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.bindService(new Intent(Activity2.this, DMService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            dmInterface = DMInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
            //do some stuff

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            dmInterface = null;
        }
    };
}
```

There are two scenarios. In the first one I get an error in the second one not (but nothing else happens).
When an error is raised depends on, where i initialize the Thread e.g. the Object that starts the Thread.

*Scenario 1:*

When I do it like described above, I get no error but nothing happens.

*Scenario 2:*

In the Service:

```
private Download dl;

private final DMInterface.Stub mBinder = new DMInterface.Stub() {

    public void downloadFile() throws DeadObjectException {
        try {
            dl = new Download();
            dl.start(url) // This starts a thread and the download

        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void stop() throws DeadObjectException {
        dl.cancel(); //This stops the download
    }

};
```

When I try to reach other parts of the service (setting a variable or something like that) everything works OK.

Comment: Is this something to do with the scope of the status variable. Have you tried making it static to see how the service deals with it then.

Comment: Hey steve, that possible, i don't know. My app is structured like this: Activity2 -> Service (here i define the variable) -> AsyncTask. Like i said, everything works correct until i disconnect from the service. If you need more code, let me know.

Comment: Hey, its me again. I made an edit to the main post, please have a look again. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post some code on a) How you start the service from activity 2 b) How you reconnect (bind) back to the service from activity. Also do you get any exception in the log ? (use for example app aLogCat to check the log). I am doing something similar in an ongoing project, but have some problems rebinding (already bound to an application) http://code.google.com/p/android-bluetooth-on-motion/

Comment: Hi dparnas, thx for your answer, you are my last hope. ;) I add the parts you asked for. See EDIT2.

Answer (score 1):

A [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) lives in its own world, being a Service it is remote from the rest of your program.
A [Binder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html) can be used to communicate with your service. Defining a [aidl](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) interface with a setStatus method allows you to communicate the status to the service.

Comment: Change hyperlink from your local source to web-source. =)

Comment: Hi Rene, thx for you answer. I know how a Service works (in general) and it works for me too until i close Aktivity2. Then i'm not able to reconnect correctly to the AsyncTask in the service but the service keeps working. The download i started in the service keeps active. If i keep the activity open, i can work with the thread so i think the reconnect to the service(AsyncTask) does not work correctly but i have no clue what exactly goes wrong.